# Is ->h_addr_list[0] the address I need?

Tags: c++, ip, ip-address, router, upnp

I am working on implementing UpNP on C++, and I need to get the local internal IP address assigned by the router to make the sockets works. The address I need is the one that appears on routers where it shows the computers connected to the router and the local IP assigned to each computer. I am using this:

```
PHOSTENT      Addr    = NULL;
char          Host[MAX_PATH];

if( gethostname(Host, sizeof(Host)) == 0 )
{
    Address = gethostbyname( Host );
    if( Address != NULL )
    {
        //*(struct in_addr *)Address->h_addr_list[0]) <- this is my address
    }
}
```

This works fine on the computer I am testing, but that computer has only one network card, so I was wondering if maybe when a computer has more than one card or network device, **Address->h_addr_list[0]** may not be the one I need and it could be in another index of that array.

Will **[0]** always retrieve the IP assigned by the router?

Comment: No.  You can't tell from the computer what IPs come from where; what if the computer has both a wired and wireless adapter?  BOTH IPs could  come from the router in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming winsock here, as per previous question)

You shouldn't assume that the first address is the correct one (as there may be multiple interfaces, and more than one may be active)

I'd recommend enumerating addresses using either [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with an empty `pNodeName` argument, or [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Both of these return a linked lists with your system's registered addresses

Answer (score 0):

> ... get the local internal IP address assigned by the router ...

Note that in some cases, the machine's IP address will be manually assigned, but the user will still want to use UPnP.

On Linux, it is suggested to use `getaddrinfo(3)` instead of `gethostbyname(3)`, perhaps Winsocks has made a similar transition?

On Linux, it is common for `/etc/hosts` to have loopback entries also accessible by hostname; `/etc/gai.conf` can be used to configure the sort order of returned addresses, and possibly a loopback address will be returned. Does Winsock make it that easy for sysadmins to change the order of returned addresses?

Don't forget that a system may legitimately have multiple upstream routers: a laptop with an EV-DO or EDGE or similar cellular data connection *and* a wireless or wired Ethernet will have multiple IPs, multiple upstream routers, and the routing table will be consulted to figure out which one should be used to send each packet.

Can you use either (a) the address used by clients to contact you? (`getsockname(2)` will return the local address used on a specific socket.) (b) ask the user to select among the list of IP addresses, if there are several? Binding to N of M interfaces would be nice, so users can select which networks get the services and which networks are left alone.